# Python 2.7 Multiprocessing Pool for a list of Strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to Python (disclaimer: I'm new to programming and I've been reading python online for two weeks) and I've written a simple multi-processing script that should allow me to use four subprocesses at once. I was using a global variable (YES, I KNOW BETTER NOW) to keep track of how many processes were running at once. Start a new process, increment by one; end a process, decrement by one. This was messy but I was only focused on getting the multi-processes working, which it does.

So far I've been doing the equivalent of:

```
processes = 0

def function(value)
    global processes
    do stuff to value
    processes-=1

While read line
    if processes < 4
        processes+=1
        create a new subprocess - function(line)
```

1: I need to keep track of processes in a better way than a global. I saw some use of a 'pool' in python to have 4 workers, but I failed hard at it. I like the idea of a pool but I don't know how to pass each line of a list to the next worker. Thoughts?

2: On general principles, why is my global var decrement not working? I know it's ugly, but I at least expected it to be ugly and successful.

3: I know I'm not locking the var before editing, I was going to add that once the decrementation was working properly.

Sorry if that's horrible pseudo-code, but I think you can see the gist. Here is the real code if you want to dive in:

```
MAX_THREADS = 4
CURRENT_THREADS = 0
MAX_LOAD = 8

# Iterate through all users in the userlist and call the funWork function on each user
def funReader(filename):

    # I defined the logger in detail above, I skipped about 200 lines of code to get it slimmed down
    logger.info("Starting 'move' function for file \"{0}\"...".format(filename))

    # Read in the entire user list file
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = file.read()
    file.close()

    for line in lines:
        user = line.rstrip()
        funControl(user)

# Accept a username and query system load and current funWork thread count; decide when to start next thread
def funControl(user):

    # Global variables that control whether a new thread starts
    global MAX_THREADS
    global CURRENT_THREADS
    global MAX_LOAD

    # Decide whether to start a new subprocess of funWork for the current user
    print
    logger.info("Trying to start a new thread for user {0}".format(user))
    sysLoad = os.getloadavg()[1]

    logger.info("The current threads before starting a new loop are: {0}.".format(CURRENT_THREADS))
    if CURRENT_THREADS < MAX_THREADS:
        if sysLoad < MAX_LOAD:
            CURRENT_THREADS+=1
            logger.info("Starting a new thread for user {0}.".format(user))
            p = Process(target=funWork, args=(user,))
            p.start()
        else:
            print "Max Load is {0}".format(MAX_LOAD)
            logger.info("System load is too high ({0}), process delayed for four minutes.".format(sysLoad))
            time.sleep(240)
            funControl(user)
    else:
        logger.info("There are already {0} threads running, user {1} delayed for ten minutes.".format(CURRENT_THREADS, user))
        time.sleep(600)
        funControl(user)

# Actually do the work for one user
def funWork(user):

    global CURRENT_THREADS

    for x in range (0,10):
        logger.info("Processing user {0}.".format(user))
        time.sleep(1)
    CURRENT_THREADS-=1
```

Lastly: any errors you see are likely to be transcription mistakes because the code executes without bugs on a server at work. However, any horrible coding practices you see are completely mine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just use multiprocessing.Pool for whatever you're trying to do?  (If load average is a concern, just have the processes pool creates check it and throttle themselves maybe; that seems a weird requirement though, and there are probably better solutions to that - renice, cgroups or something).

Comment: Yes there is timday, and the reason is that I don't know how to pass each line to the processing pool. Do you mind expanding a little on how I'd do that? I have read plenty of examples of a 4 worker pool, but I don't know how to pass each line from the file to a new process. Edit: tried to hit enter for a 'thank you' line for giving me a quick answer, but apparently that just submits this post.

Comment: Aaron has supplied an answer which shows how to use pool.map (which is exactly what I'd be using for this sort of thing too).  Note that pool just creates a pool of worker processes once when the pool is created as that can be much more efficient than creating a fresh process for each line processed.

Answer (score 2):

how about this:  (not tested)

```
MAX_PROCS = 4

# Actually do the work for one user
def funWork(user):

    for x in range (0,10):
        logger.info("Processing user {0}.".format(user))
        time.sleep(1)
    return

# Iterate through all users in the userlist and call the funWork function on each user
def funReader(filename):

    # I defined the logger in detail above, I skipped about 200 lines of code to get it slimmed down
    logger.info("Starting 'move' function for file \"{0}\"...".format(filename))

    # Read in the entire user list file
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = file.read()
    file.close()

    work = []
    for line in lines:
        user = line.rstrip()
        work.append(user)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=MAX_PROCS)  #threads are different from processes...
    return pool.map(funWork, work)
```

Comment: [here's](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html#The-Pool-class) a great refrence for using pools.

Comment: Aaron, I'm testing your suggestions now. That doc on pools is great, thanks! Regarding threads vs processes: I started thinking I'd need threads because the person at my job that threw this at me said 'threads'. After doing my own research I realized I needed processes, but my original code still said threads before I knew better. I'm fixing it too, and I appreciate the distinction!

Comment: No Problem! I have in fact created my own processing pool class of sorts by manually creating a pool of worker processes, however the default implementation is often good enough. I simply wanted a bit extra functionality for my processing pool (estimated time left to complete job, exact number of jobs left to complete, etc...). Good luck with your project!